# Get unparsed parameters in click application

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

In `click` application from `Context` we can get command name, its full path and parsed parameters like below. Can we get *unparsed* parameters from `click`?

*Edit*: updated question according to @[julaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7465516/julaine) and @[Marco Parola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22515567/marco-parola) comments

**abc** script contents:

```py
#!/home/user/.bin/python-tools/venv/bin/python3

import sys
import click

@click.group("abc")
def abc():
    """ABC Help"""
    pass

@abc.command("test")
@click.option("-o", "--option")
@click.option("-o2", "--option2", default="two")
def test(option, option2):
    """Get command CLI info"""
    ctx = click.get_current_context()
    print("Command name:", ctx.info_name)
    print("Command path:", ctx.command_path)
    print("Command params:", ctx.params)
    print("CLI args with Click:", "???")

    # Try it with click.Context.args
    print("\nCommand leftover args:", ctx.args)
    # Try it with sys.argv
    cmd_path = click.get_current_context().command_path.split()
    cli_args = sys.argv[len(cmd_path):]
    print("CLI args with sys.argv:", " ".join(cli_args))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc()
```

We get in responce:

```bash
❯ abc test -o 1
Command name: test
Command path: abc test
Command params: {'option': '1', 'option2': 'two'}
CLI args with Click: ???

Command leftover args: []
CLI args with sys.argv: -o 1
```

Can one get unparsed parameters from `click` itself, i.e. without `sys.argv`? In the example above it should return:

```bash
CLI args with Click: -o 1
```

Comment: why do you not want to use `sys.argv`?

Comment: I assumed click stores CLI args but this assumption may be wrong.

With `sys.argv` we can do
`cmd_path = click.get_current_context().command_path.split()` and
`cli_args = sys.argv[len(cmd_path):]`

Answer (score 0):

In `click`, you can obtain the unparsed CLI arguments using the args attribute of the `click.Context`. And it returns you a list.

```
import click

@click.group("abc")
def abc():
    """ABC Help"""
    pass

@abc.command("test")
@click.option("-o", "--option")
@click.option("-o2", "--option2", default="two")
def test(option, option2):
    """Get command CLI info"""
    ctx = click.get_current_context()
    print("Command name:", ctx.info_name)
    print("Command path:", ctx.command_path)
    print("Command params:", ctx.params)
    print("CLI args:", ' '.join(ctx.args))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc()
```

Comment: Thank you for the responce! I get an empty list from `click.Context.args`. That is the thing. [Docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#context) state that `click.Context.args` is for "leftover arguments". Maybe that counts? This is the case for shell script. Updated the code accordingly

Comment: @dev7 if the answer solves your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @julaine No it does not. `ctx.args` in this answer returns an empty array in my tests

Comment: @dev7 sorry I misread your comment, I am tired.

Comment: @julaine it's ok, thank you :) Missing here anything just pushes me forward to be more specific and clear in question post, so I have updated it in that direction